# Import data in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

What if I want to create some Account entites based on some information stored in a local file (.txt, .xlsx, ecc.), would I have to use a plugin to be able to read the data in the way I want or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

There is an out-of-the-box import tool for CRM 2011 that allows you to bring in .csv files and a few other formats.  You simply need to have the adequate permissions and go to the correct tab.  (I would direct more but I don't have access to a CRM install at the moment.)

I mention .csv specifically because it worked the best for me in the past.

Once you begin the upload you will be able to go through their wizard to map the fields to what you want them to be.  You can even save the mapping for later use.

[Edit]
There is more info on the built-in tool here to get you started: http://www.powerobjects.com/2010/10/01/crm-2011-data-import-wizard/